# Windows 7 laptop wireless issue. Forgetting managed wireless networks

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-adapter

There is a laptop that is giving us some issues when connecting to wifi. Sometimes it will say trouble connecting as soon as you finish typing in the password like it didn't even try. The real problem is it forgets wifi networks so you have to type the password in everytime. I have disable/reenabled the NIC, I've downloaded the latest drivers, and now I'm wondering what to do from here.

The unuasal thing is I can have the "Manage Wireless Networks" window open. Say I just connected to WIFIA. It shows up in the list. Now I go and join WIFIB, as soon as the computer has disconnected from WIFIA it drops from the remembered wireless networks list.

I'm looking for any troubleshooting tips or settings options that might be causing this kind of behavior. Thanks for any help. It will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but **in my opinion** (and I stress this is my opinion) that sounds like a WiFi card starting to fault.

I say this as I have had similar faults on an HP DV7-2022tx Laptop and replacing the WiFi card cured it immediately.

--- EDIT ---

I did some searching on Microsoft Technet.  It would seem you are not alone (assuming I have understood the problem correctly!!)

A solution offered that seemed to meet the approval of a large amount of people was as follows:

1. run msconfig (start > run (or just type into the "Search programs and files" field above the windows orb) > msconfig)
   this brings up the System Configuration dialog box
2. click the Startup tab
3. scroll to find your wifi adapter's startup program (in my case it was NETGEAR)
4. uncheck the box next to this startup item
5. restart your computer. problem solved (apparently ...)

I have also linked to the article [HERE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-will-not-remember-wireless-network-key/63d2ce51-371a-48e4-b1ae-c349e4f51fde) to make sure it is the same issue you are facing.

Comment: WiFi card was replaced and the issue persists.

Comment: OK, well we can probably rule out the WiFi card then - Good.
Does this laptop do this on ANY WiFi Network? or only on the network you are using it on at present? (Home network?)
What type / model of router are you connecting through?

Comment: @casual_loser I have edited my original answer to include a _possible_ solution ... please don't hold it against me if I have misunderstood :-)

Comment: Thank you Dario. Sorry I haven't been back to check here. Actually your edit turns out to be correct. I went to msconfig and noticed the laptop was set to selective startup. I set it to normal, restarted and the issue was gone.

Comment: @casual_loser - Excellent news; very happy you are staying connected :-)